# Why is there a possibility that UITableViewCells can be nil within a row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm currently learning the inner-workings of UITableView through a Ray Wunderlich book and noticed that in this protocal's function body it uses optional binding to create a cell.

```
override func tableView(tableView:  UITableView , didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
    if cell.accessoryType == .None {
      cell. accessoryType = .Checkmark
    } else  {
      cell.accessoryType = .None
    }
  }

  tableView. deselectRowAtIndexPath (indexPath, animated: true )
}
```

The concept of optional binding is still fairly new to me so thinking aloud I'm assuming that there's the possibility that there **won't** be a cell in every row (i.e. returns `nil`)

Here's where I'm getting stuck. In my storyboard I have a table view controller and one prototype cell. Shouldn't the fact that I have this one prototype cell in the table view ensure that there will be created for however many rows are created?

Comment: Read the documentation for `UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It states: *"An object representing a cell of the table, or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range."*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `func cellForRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?` method of `UITableView` is defined to return an optional, which is why you have to first unwrap it.

According to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:): `An object representing a cell of the table, or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.`

Comment: In a real world situation, when would there ever be a cell that's not visible or the indexPath that's out of range? I guess that's the part I'm having a hard time understanding.

Comment: @CarlEdwards If you're just using the `indexPath` provided to you by `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you will not have a problem because it will only call this for cells that are visible and for a valid `indexPath`. But `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is just a method on `UITableView` so it could be called from anywhere with any kind of input. There's nothing prevent you from creating your own `indexPath` that points to some row that doesn't exist. For example if your table view has 3 rows and you call `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 10, inSection: 0))`, it will return `nil`